# How can I do it in my bot?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new here and I have a question
I want to create telegram bot 
and I want to send to every member in this bot a message that only him can see it
what I mean if I have 100 person on my bot 
I want to send 100 message to 100 person but every person will get 1 message
and all the 100 people will get different message to another one
so how can I do it ?
please enlighten me ...

Answer (score 0):

this is simple GET method:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=<text>
```

`chat_id` is unique for any user, you can send one, two or more different message to any user - just use different `chat_id` and text.

or if you want to sent one message to all user - just call this get method with one text and diff `chat_id`